# Collider2d not working when game restarted after player die

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, restart, collider

I've checked the In-Game Restart button, it works like a charm, player still can be hurt by colliding with the obstacle, but when the player die and press Restart button, the player won't collide with any obstacle,

So i think it's because my "void Die", but i only disable a few also it still works when i restart the game, only the player won't collide with any obstacle, just that... Help Me!

```cs
public void Die() {
    //Disable Score
    ScoreCounter.SetActive(false);

    //Animation
    AN.Play("Death");

    //Stop Coroutine
    StopCoroutine("Invulnerability");

    //Load Restart Menu
    PanelRestart.SetActive(true);

    //Disable Object Function
    GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
    this.enabled = false;
}
```

and this is my pause button script, i used this both in-game pause button and then restart, and when the player die and then restart

```cs
public void RestartButton() {
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
}
```

Comment: Your StopCoroutine call is false. See the Unity Documentation on how to do it correctly. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please can you explain what should i do? i've see the link you mention but it confuse me since i'm new to this, i get those script from Youtube Tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I restart the game, only the player won't collide with any
> obstacle

It's highly likely that your collisions aren't the problem, but your [`StopCoroutine()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) call is. As it currently won't stop the `"Invulnerability"` of the player and therefore he won't die once he collides.

To fix that you need to adjust your [`StopCoroutine()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) call like this, you could either:

1. Keep the `IEnumerator` Method as a private member.
2. Keep the started [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) as a private member.

---

**IEnumerator Example:**

```cs
// Keep the executing script as a private variable.
// This is needed to stop it with StopCoroutine.
private IEnumerator coroutine;

void Start() {
    coroutine = ExampleIEnumerator();
    // Start the given Coroutine.
    StartCoroutine(coroutine);
    // Stop the given Coroutine.
    StopCoroutine(coroutine);
}

private IEnumerator ExampleIEnumerator() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
}
```

**Coroutine Example:**

```cs
// Keep the executed coroutine as a private variable.
// This is needed to stop it with StopCoroutine.
private Coroutine coroutine;

void Start() {
    // Start the given Coroutine.
    coroutine = StartCoroutine(ExampleIEnumerator());
    // Stop the given Coroutine.
    StopCoroutine(coroutine);
}

private IEnumerator ExampleIEnumerator() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
}
```

---

Additionally you also need to re-enable your `CapsuleCollider2D` after disabling it when you die.

```cs
GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>().enabled = true;
```

[StopCoroutine Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html)

Comment: Thankyou for helping me out, but i've tried the first example, the player still invicible when die and restarted, the second example gave me 2 error

Oh, i forgot to mention, i've add an Invicible icon when the player is hurt it will show and it gone when Invicible time ran out, but when die and restarted the icon are not showing, also i've try using debug.log it not tell me if the player are invicible

Comment: Can you tell me the error you are getting with the second example.

Comment: And you probably need to enable the Capsule Collider after restarting. ```GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>().enabled = true;```

Comment: Gosh, the second method are work 100% after i put ```GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>().enabled = true;``` at void Start
Thankyou so much! Such a long time for me to figure it out haha...